# How to extract text from pdf line by line in python 2.7

Tags: python

I'm trying to read and parse a PDF file containing a table...

This is the table in the PDF:

[Table in pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCzM6.png)

and this is my code:

```
import PyPDF2
import re
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader , PdfFileWriter
FileRead = open("C:\\Users\\Zahraa Jawad\\S40rooms.pdf", 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(FileRead)
pdfwriter = PdfFileWriter()
for page in pdfReader.pages:
    print page.extractText()
```

What I want is to read each line ( split ) in the table separately and save all information in the line ( YEAR, SEMESTER, ROOM, DAY, COURSE NO, INSTRUCTOR, TIME FROM, TIME TO, NUMBER OF STUDENTS ) in an array. After each '\n', I'd like to save the data in a new index in the array.

However, my code does not work; it reads all the information and returns it as a paragraph! I don't know how to split each line.

For example ( See the PDF above ):

341 458 01 Gazwa Sleebekh UTH 09:00 09:50 30

Output: YEAR, SEMESTER, ROOM, DAY, COURSE NO, INSTRUCTOR, TIME FROM, TIME TO, NUMBER OF STUDENTS

2015/2016, Second, S40-021, U, 341, Ghazwa Sleebekh, 09:00, 09:50, 30  2015/2016, Second, S40-021, T, 341, Ghazwa Sleebekh, 09:00, 09:50, 30  2015/2016, Second, S40-021, H, 341, Ghazwa Sleebekh, 09:00, 09:50, 30

It's split by the UTH ( Day ) but my problem is how to read each line in the PDF and search within it using a regular expression :)

Comment: Could you give us an example of the output? Just the relevant sections of `page.extractText()` in case it's a long text.

Comment: You might be interested in [Tabula](http://tabula.technology). Also, you can use `str.split` to split strings, or the `re` module for pattern matching, or `csv` for tabular data, or [`pyparsing`](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com) for more complex, structured data.

Comment: Ok I will post an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In converting PDF to text I've had the best results with using `pdftotext` from the [poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) utilities. (You can find ms-windows binaries in several places [[1]](http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/), [[2]](https://sourceforge.net/projects/poppler-win32/).)

```
import subprocess

def pdftotext(pdf, page=None):
    """Retrieve all text from a PDF file.

    Arguments:
        pdf Path of the file to read.
        page: Number of the page to read. If None, read all the pages.

    Returns:
        A list of lines of text.
    """
    if page is None:
        args = ['pdftotext', '-layout', '-q', pdf, '-']
    else:
        args = ['pdftotext', '-f', str(page), '-l', str(page), '-layout',
                '-q', pdf, '-']
    try:
        txt = subprocess.check_output(args, universal_newlines=True)
        lines = txt.splitlines()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        lines = []
    return lines
```

Note that text extraction only works if the PDF file actually contains text! Some PDF files only contain scanned images of text, in which case you'll need an OCR solution.